# What do I have to do to unlock activities in other parts of Steelport?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

One of the things I enjoy about the Saints Row series is the side activities: Insurance Fraud and that kind of thing. I'd like to play more of them, but right now I only have activities unlocked in one area, the central Morning Star-controlled area. (Nine of sixteen are currently unlocked.) The other parts of town have 0 of 15, 0 of 13, and 0 of 12 unlocked.

What do I have to do to unlock activities in other parts of town? I've completed 9 missions overall: the last one was Trafficking. Do I have to complete more missions or more activities? Do I have to reach a certain level of respect? Can someone help a fellow Saint out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to first beat the "Easy" level of each Diversion before the "Medium" and "Hard" levels will unlock.**

Unlike Saints Row 2, the levels of each Diversion are divided into separate areas. In SR2, you did level 1-3 of a Diversion in one area and 4-6 of a Diversion in another. In SR3, all levels of the Diversions are separate and are spread across the districts.

Weirdly enough, the "Easy" versions of some of the Diversions are part of the main storyline and required to do to advance the main story. So you may have to advance further in the storyline to get to some of these missions' "Easy" versions before you'll be able to unlock their "Medium" and "Hard" versions.

Comment: dislike. I don't want to do Heli Assault just yet.

Comment: Hmm ... wait, I think I misunderstood your answer. Let's take Insurance Fraud as an example. I have only three versions of it unlocked: Easy in Sunset Park, Medium in Henry Steel Mills, and Hard in Loren Square. I've completed all three. What do I have to do to unlock more Insurance Fraud?

Comment: Ah, I see. The main storyline unlocks the Easy ones, and then completing Easy in that district unlocks Medium and Hard. Excellent ... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check your map often, and spend time driving around. The various levels of each activity are scattered around the districts; when you see a blue icon marked "?" on the city map, that's an activity that you haven't checked out yet. Once you get close enough, you'll see which activity it is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I'm not referring to activities that are already on the map and unidentified. I'm talking about activities that are not yet on the map. Even if you blanket the city and thoroughly explore locations where activities will appear, they will not appear if you have not progressed far enough in the main storyline.